# Flutter how do I make the title show only once and the image will still showing under the same title

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would want to make my workshopName appear only once if it is the same workshopName. The image will then go under the same workshopName. Right now My code is showing one title and one image even though the title is the same. Basically i have 2 files
gallery_box.dart

```
Widget galleryBox(Function(String workshop)? onTap, QueryDocumentSnapshot doc) {
  final workshopName = doc["workshop"] as String;

  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      if (onTap != null) {
        onTap(workshopName);
      }
    },
    child: Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // Row for "workshop" (not clickable)
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(doc["workshop"], style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text("Long Press to delete", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              )),
            ],
          ),
          // Container with a fixed 3x3 aspect ratio for the image (clickable)
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (onTap != null) {
                onTap(workshopName);
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 120,
              child: FutureBuilder<String?>(
                future: getImageUrlForCurrentUser(doc),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Icon(Icons.error_outline, size: 120);
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Image.network(
                      snapshot.data!,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Icon(Icons.image, size: 120);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}



Future<String?> getImageUrlForCurrentUser(QueryDocumentSnapshot workshopDoc) async {
  // Access the "UserData" document and retrieve the "imageUrl" field
  String? imageUrl = workshopDoc.get(
      'imageUrl'); // these 2 lines creating error
  return imageUrl;
  // }
  // }
}
```

and the other files is gallery.dart

```
Expanded(
  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Gallery").where("email", isEqualTo: userEmail).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((workshop) {
            final workshopData = workshop.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            if (workshopData.containsKey('workshop')) {
              String workshopName = workshopData['workshop'];
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0), // Add margin to create a gap
                child: galleryBox((workshopName) {
                  // Handle the onTap action
                }, workshop),
              );
            }
            return Container(); // Handle the case where 'carName' doesn't exist in the document
          }).toList(),
        );
      }
      return Text("There's no car");
    },
  ),
)
```